# Insert an array to sql's table with stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this :

```
keyword (table name)        
----------------    
kid   key   
----------------    
1     asp.net   
2     php   
3     C#‎   
4     vb
```

In a webform page, i have a textbox that user can insert string like below :

```
asp.net,php,C#‎,vb,css
```

i must insert this string in another table like below:

```
p-tag (table name)
----------------
pid  kid
----------------
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
```

i must first check that those word in string exist in Keyword,or not. if yes insert them in p-tag table. 
I can perform this with C# code , but i want do with stored procedure.
Is it possible?
**note :** my english is weak, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest passing the keywords as a table-value parameter. Refer to this article to find out more about it - [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There's also a good C# example on how to use it. Then it is fairly easy to accomplish what you need with a single query. First create a type for table-value parameter:

```
    CREATE TYPE dbo.TableTypeName AS TABLE
        ( keyName nvarchar(50) )
```

Then use it in the procedure like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateTags 
    (@tableParameter dbo.TableTypeName READONLY, @tagId INT)
AS
INSERT [p-tag](pid, kid)
SELECT @tagId, K.kid from @tableParameter tP
inner join [keyword] K on key = tP.keyName
```

This will insert only values which exist in keyword table.

Hope it helps!